# <div> resize handle in AJAX RadEditor appearing in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, html, content-management-system, telerik, radeditor

I am using an AJAX RadEditor from Telerik in a CMS that I am working on.  Everything seems to work well in Firefox, but I have noticed some strange behavior in IE.  Namely, when content is put in a , it becomes very difficult to manage.  Clicking on the content contained in the  creates a striped border, with resize handles attached to it, around the full area of the .  This tends to include area that is outside the containing RadEditor.  It also causes the cursor to turn into a drag cursor and makes the content draggable.  This makes it difficult to actually select the content.

This only happens in IE, and I'm wondering if there is a way to disable this behavior.  It is frustrating my clients in their attempts to use the CMS, and unfortunately simply switching to Firefox is not a workable solution for them.  Has anyone else encountered this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that this is the default editor behavior - in any case you can compare IE and Firefox on the RadEditor [online demos](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/default/defaultcs.aspx). The behavior on your site could be caused by a global CSS style, which is also applied in the editor content area.

Comment: You are definitely correct about this being caused by a CSS style.  The problem <div>s have a class applied to them which gives the following styles:

    text-align:left;  width:462px; float:left;

Unfortunately, I can't just remove these styles.  Is there any way to disable this behavior while leaving the styles intact?

Comment: You can try using an external CSS file and override the div behavior in the editor content area - http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/externalcssfiles.html